# Getting information out of a PHP object

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to make my way through an inherited Yii Framework site.  Very little Object Oriented knowledge previously.

I'm printing some user information to see what is there like this...

```
print_r(Yii::app()->user);
```

And that's printing out this...

```
CWebUser Object (
[allowAutoLogin] => 1
[guestName] => Guest
[loginUrl] => Array
    (
        [0] => /site/login
    )

[identityCookie] => 
[authTimeout] => 7200
[autoRenewCookie] => 
[autoUpdateFlash] => 1
[loginRequiredAjaxResponse] => 
[_keyPrefix:CWebUser:private] => 7c6285462394c9a141b5d66dce54e8f2
[_access:CWebUser:private] => Array
    (
        [Admin] => 
        [Judge] => 
        [Student] => 1
    )

[behaviors] => Array
    (
    )

[_initialized:CApplicationComponent:private] => 1
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

I'm trying to get out the information that this user is a Student.  I see it!  It's ]there!

```
[Student] => 1
```

But how would I get that information out?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the parts of CWebUser that appear to have something to do with _access

```
private $_access=array();


    public function checkAccess($operation,$params=array(),$allowCaching=true)
{
    if($allowCaching && $params===array() && isset($this->_access[$operation]))
        return $this->_access[$operation];

    $access=Yii::app()->getAuthManager()->checkAccess($operation,$this->getId(),$params);
    if($allowCaching && $params===array())
        $this->_access[$operation]=$access;

    return $access;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump(Yii::app()->user->Student)`?

Comment: Its a private property. As such you cannot access it from outside of the object directly. Likely a method exists that allows you to check access levels. Look at your `CWebUser` class.

Comment: You should learn basics about objects, and you find out it easly. Without that, you will likely not be able to manage that website. Also it looks weird that `CWebUser` has some `_access` field, as `CWebUser` is core Yii class, however some derived class could have such field.

Answer (score 3):

The following should tell you whether the user has 'Student' access:

`$isStudent = Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Student') == 1;`

Comment: For completeness sake, here's the link to the documentation for [checkAccess()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail)

Answer (score 1):

'student' is part of the $_access array. But $_access is private so you can not access it directly.

But there must be a method (function) to get it!
look in the `CWebUser` class there should be a method like

```
getStudent();

isStudent();
```

or may be

```
$access = getAccess();
$access['student'];
```

Edit:
[checkAccess](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail)
seems to be used someting like this `checkAccess('student');`

Comment: I added in the question what I see in the CWebUser class that has to do with _access

Comment: @d.raev Since you're guessing, this should really be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @ernie it looked as a simple PHP OOP question at first, but you are right.